# Speeding up random minimum spanning tree in networkx?

Tags: python, optimization, networkx

Here's a bit of code whose goal is to build a random spanning tree using greedy and random edge weights. It runs much slower than I would like it to. Any tips for ways to speed it up?

Both the randomly generating weights *and* the sampling of a minimum spanning tree are slow... the first is especially weird to me, because there are only 179400 edges and np.random.uniform(0,1,179400) executes very quickly.

(Here slow means on the order of seconds.)

(I'm happy to use something other than networkx,but it's not preferable.)

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

graph = nx.grid_graph([300, 300])

for edge in graph.edges():
    graph.edges[edge]["weight"] = np.random.uniform(0, 1)

tree = nx.minimum_spanning_tree(graph)
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there something I can do to improve this question?

Answer (score 2):

If bulk production of random numbers is quicker in your tests, then just do that.

```
rand = np.random.uniform(0, 1, graph.edges.size())
i = 0
for edge in graph.edges():
    graph.edges[edge]["weight"] = rand[i]
    i += 1
```

Comment: This approximately doubles the speed, but it is still very weird to me that it takes 4 seconds to go through the list of 179400 edges and set their weight variables...

Comment: @Lorenzo Well if the problem is inside the loop, then maybe it is because there is one or two dictionary lookups happening in every iteration? It is possible that this is slow.

Comment: @Lorenzo The networkx documentation says the fast way to iterate over the edges is by using the adjacency lists directly: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-edges-and-neighbors